# Syntax errors for keywords in pydev plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, pydev

I'm using the Pydev plugin for Eclipse Luna for Java EE.

The python code runs correctly, but errors are showing up for built in keywords like `print`.

Error: `Undefined Variable: print`

I looked on stackoverflow for other answers, and the suggestions have all been to manually configure an interpreter. I changed my interpreter to point at C:/python34/python.exe, but this has not fixed the problem. I also made sure that I was using grammar version 3.0.

Update: I think it might be a problem with aptana instead of pydev. I uninstalled aptana, and installed pydev without any issues. But when I tried to reinstall aptana, I can only do it by uninstalling pydev. I need a way to try a previous version of aptana or else a way to install aptana and pydev separately

Comment: Could you give a code snippet of what you are trying?

Comment: I just set up pydev in eclipse and was testing it out. It was literally just: print ("hello")

Comment: First testing with minimal code is a great idea.  If the problem was only with `print`, I would wonder if there were some 2 versus 3 issue. But you have suggested otherwise. Does something like `int('1')` give the same error?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, and I'm getting undefined variable: int.

Comment: I think it might be a problem with aptana, not pydev actually, see update

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Eclipse Luna does not provide support for PyDev when it's installed with Aptana. I was able to install Aptana without PyDev and do a separate install of Pydev on its own and this solved the problem.